# USB Joystick support building VICE from source?

Tags: emulation

I'm building vice from source (r33116) in Ubuntu 14.04 and get this from `./configure`:

```
INPUT
-----
Joystick support            : yes
Mouse support               : yes
Lightpen support            : yes
Linux style joystick support: yes
BSD style joystick support  : no 
Digital joystick support    : no 
USB joystick support        : no
```

I see this section in configure.ac:

```
  dnl NetBSD/FreeBSD USB joystick support
  usbhid_header=no
  usbhid_lib=no
  usb_lib=no
  AC_CHECK_LIB(usbhid, hid_get_report_desc, usbhid_lib=yes)
  if test x"$usbhid_lib" = "xyes" ; then
    AC_CHECK_HEADER(usbhid.h,
                    [AC_DEFINE(HAVE_USBHID_H,1,
                      [Define to 1 if you have the <usbhid.h> header file.])
                    usb_header=yes])
    AC_CHECK_HEADER(libusbhid.h,
                    [AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LIBUSBHID_H,1,
                      [Define to 1 if you have the <libusbhid.h> header file.])
                    usb_header=yes])

    if test x"$usb_header" = "xyes" ; then
      AC_DEFINE(HAS_USB_JOYSTICK,,[Enable emulation for USB joysticks.])
      JOY_LIBS="-lusbhid"
      HAS_USB_JOYSTICK_SUPPORT="yes"
    fi
  else
    AC_CHECK_LIB(usb, hid_get_report_desc, usb_lib=yes)
    if test x"$usb_lib" = "xyes"; then
      AC_CHECK_HEADER(usb.h,
                      [AC_DEFINE(HAVE_USB_H,1,
                        [Define to 1 if you have the <usb.h> header file.])
                      usb_header=yes])
      AC_CHECK_HEADER(libusb.h,
                      [AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LIBUSB_H,1,
                        [Define to 1 if you have the <libusb.h> header file.])
                      usb_header=yes])
      if test x"$usb_header" = "xyes" ; then
        AC_DEFINE(HAS_USB_JOYSTICK,,[Enable emulation for USB joysticks.])
        JOY_LIBS="-lusb"
        HAS_USB_JOYSTICK_SUPPORT="yes"
      fi
    fi
  fi
```

I have `/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h` (I don't think Ubuntu has packages with libusbhid.h or usbhid.h), shouldn't the above be finding it?

Answer (score 5):

That whole section is titled “NetBSD/FreeBSD USB joystick support” and is only relevant on BSD. On Linux, USB joysticks are supported using the “Linux style joystick support” (all joysticks are managed in the same way).

The Ubuntu build logs report exactly the same features (see the latest [amd64 logs](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/300122151/buildlog_ubuntu-zesty-amd64.vice_3.0.0.dfsg-2_BUILDING.txt.gz) for example).